# Using Underscore Method 'find' on a Backbone Collection

Tags: collections, backbone.js, find, underscore.js

I'm trying to use the Underscore method 'find' on a collection but it is not giving me the results I expected:

I have a base model with no defaults, and a default collection. The models in my collection have only two attributes: tranId(a guid as a string), and perform(a function to perform).

I'm trying to find the item in the collection that matches the tranId that I pass it...

```
    var tranId = "1a2b3c";

    var found = _.find(myCollection, function(item){
        return item.tranId === tranId;
    });
```

Found is always undefined, even though the debugger shows that my collection does, indeed have an item in it where tranId matches my variable. I am unable to set a breakpoint at the return statement to see what item.tranId equates to. I have also tried this...

```
    var found = _.find(myCollection, function(item){
        return item.get('tranId') === tranId;
    });
```

But, same thing. 'found' is always undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Backbone collection implements [many of the Underscore functions](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods), so you could do this:

```
var found = myCollection.find(function(item){
        return Number(item.get('tranId')) === tranId;
});
```

Also to debug if the values are not what you expect try:

```
var found = myCollection.find(function(item){
        console.log('Checking values', item, item.get('tranId'), tranId);   
        return Number(item.get('tranId')) === tranId;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why doesn't the Underscore method work in the same way? It should also be noted that the tranId is a string, not a number. So, the typecasting is not needed.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle if you want to use underscore methods directly may be is better to use myCollection.models because it is raw Array of your models http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models -- the typecast was in case that there was issues with the strict datatyping comparision. :D

Answer (score 11):

A more simple one:

```
var found = myCollection.findWhere({'tranId': tranId})
```

See [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) for details.

If you must use Underscore method:

```
var found = _.find(myCollection.models, function(item){
    return item.get('tranId') === tranId;
});
```

Because myCollection.models is an array, myCollection not.

I prefer the former one.

Comment: Very nice. I like the one line solution!

Answer (score 6):

A collection does not mean exactly the same thing in Backbone (an object managing a list of models) and Underscore (a list of objects). What you should pass to `_.find` is `myCollection.models`

```
_.find(myCollection.models, function(model) {
    return model.get('tranId')===tranId;
});
```

As @Daniel Aranda explained, Backbone proxies [Underscore methods on collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) and you could write your example as

```
myCollection.find(function(model) {
    return model.get('tranId')===tranId;
});
```

Finally, if `tranId` is your model ID, you could [set id as the idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) and simplify the whole thing by using `get`

```
var M=Backbone.Model.extend({
   idAttribute: "tranId"
});
var C=Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:M
});

var myCollection=new C([
    {tranId:'not this one'} ,
    {tranId:'another'} ,
    {tranId:'1a2b3c'}
]);

myCollection.get(tranId);
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rYPLU/

Comment: Very useful, thanks!

Just as an aside comment remember that the default `idAttribute` of a Backbone model is the `id` field, [read the doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) for more info